# bootstrap select option multiple selection not inserting all selected options

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-modal

I have bootstrap chosen-select multiple select option. It is wokring fine but when i go to insert multiple selections into database it doesnt insert all selected options it inserts only the biggest value from the selected options.

**Select Box**

```
<select name="type" data-placeholder="Choose a Card Type..." class="chosen-select" style="text-align: left;" tabindex="2" multiple>
<?php 
$q_all_categories = mysql_query("SELECT * from sort_kcc");
while ($all_categories = mysql_fetch_array($q_all_categories)) {
    $category_id = $all_categories['id'];
    $categories_name = $all_categories['ename'];
    $categories_aname = $all_categories['aname'];

    $q_selected_cat = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM rel_sort_kcc WHERE sort_id=".$category_id."
    AND sr_id=".$_GET['id']."
    ");
    $selected = "";
    while ($category = mysql_fetch_array($q_selected_cat)) {
$selected_category  = $category['sort_id'];
if($category_id == $selected_category){$selected = "selected";}
    }
    print   "<option class='ur' ".$selected." value='".$category_id."'>".$categories_name."</option>";
    $selected = "";
}
?>
</select>
```

**Insert Query**

```
$categoriesCT   = $_POST['type'];
for($i=0; $i < count($categoriesCT); $i++) {
    mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO
            rel_sort_kcc
            (sr_id, sort_id)
        VALUES
            ('".$_POST['idName']."', '".$categoriesCT[$i]."')
    ");
}
```

Comment: first of all remove the insert query from foreach loop. And use query that can insert multiple values in single exucution. Try to make that query. And if possible debug, whther u r getting all values in post from select element. Also, display insert query, just to make sure.

Comment: @Purushottamzende i tried but no use would you please give me example?

Comment: `name="type[]"` ?

Comment: give name of select box name as array like " <select name="type[]" ", rest is right. But plz insert query outside the loop and use multiple insert query.